# How can pointwise boundedness on an interval prove uniform boundedness on a sub-interval?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Edit:

I'm trying to use contradiction.  Suppose on a compact subinterval [c,d] $f_n(x)$ is not uniformly bounded over all x and for all n=1,2,...

Now cut the interval in half and look at the subinterval [d,e]...

If we do not get a uniform bound on this subinterval, cut in half again and repeat the procedure...

Eventually we would reach a singleton ...

Hmm...

Assume that $f_n(x)$ is continuous over the interval [a,b], and that for each x in [a,b], ${f_n(x)}$ is bounded. Prove that there is a subinterval in  [a,b] such that $f_n(x)$ is uniformly bounded on this subinterval.

Any hints on how to get started on this problem are welcome.

Thanks,

Comment: Hint: Take a compact subset.

Comment: Hi @Vader, hmm each $f_n$ being cts on a compact subset [c,d] attains a max.  Now ... how can I get a max on this subset not just over all x in this subset, but over all n, too?

Comment: I'm laughing at your edit because I am typing up an answer as we speak, and I am trying to work out the exact same idea that you just typed in your edit.  So we are both thinking about the exact same type of solution at the same time.  Weird!

Comment: Hahah @user46944 :-)

Comment: The singleton we converge to ... does not cause a contradiction, so it's tricky.  We already assumed pointwise boundedness @user46944 ... hmmm

Comment: @LebronJames I posted my answer.  I may have to add some detail at the end to further justify why the last sequence is unbounded...but I'm pretty sure the argument isn't flawed.  Read through it and let me know if you see any flaws or if you have any questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Baire category argument would be recommended here, rather than a compactness argument like the nested interval attack.

For each integer $m=1,2,3, ...$ define the set
$$E_m = \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty \{x \in [a,b]: |f_n(x)| \leq m\}.$$
Since each $f_n$ is continuous, each set $E_m$ is closed.  Also, since each sequence $\{f_n(t)\}$ is bounded for a fixed $t\in [a,b]$ this means that
every point of $[a,b]$ is in one of the sets $E_1$, $E_2$, $E_3$, ...

No interval can be expressed as the union of a sequence of closed nowhere dense sets (thankyou Baire) so one of the sets $E_M$ (say) contains an interval $[c,d]$.  On that interval $|f_n(x)|\leq M$ for all $n$.

---

**Example**.  Here is an example to show that continuity is indeed needed here.  Let $\{r_n\}$ be an enumeration of the rationals in $[0,1]$.  For each $n=1,2,3, ...$ let $f_n(r_n)=n$ and $f_n(x)=0$ if $x\not=r_n$.  Each function $f_n$ is bounded but has a single point of discontinuity.  Certainly $\{f_n(t)\}$ is bounded for each fixed $t\in [0,1]$.  There is, however, no subinterval of $[0,1]$ on which $\{f_n\}$ is uniformly bounded since any such interval  contains infinitely many rationals.

Comment: Hi @b.s.thomson you define your sets using an infinite intersection - should it instead be a union of sets?  Thanks,

Comment: I want the condition to hold *for all* $n$.  Besides a *union* wouldn't be closed anyway.   For others following, the discussion has now moved to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1549539/how-to-achieve-uniform-boundedness-without-functional-analysis.

Answer (score 1):

What do we know?  Well, each $f_{n}$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, and thus bounded.

Also, for each $x \in [a,b]$, the sequence of real numbers $\{|f_{n}(x)| \}_{n = 1}^{\infty}$ is bounded by some $M_{x} > 0$ (in fact, let's let $M_{x}$ be the *smallest* such bound).

Now, we can't say that this implies $\{f_{n}\}$ is uniformly bounded on $[a,b]$, because the $M_{x}$'s could get arbitrarily large.

But we need to prove that on some sub-interval, the $M_{x}$'s can't get arbitrarily large, i.e., that for some sub-interval $[c,d]$, $\sup \limits_{x \in [c,d]} M_{x} < \infty$.  In this case, we could then let $M = \sup \limits_{x \in [c,d]} M_{x}$ and so we would have $|f_{n}| \leq M$ for all $n$ and $x \in [c,d]$, i.e., we would have a uniform bound.
$\text{ }$

---

Let's prove this by contradiction.  Suppose for each sub-interval $[c,d]$, $\sup \limits_{x \in [c,d]} M_{x} \not < \infty$.  Then if we consider the midpoint of $[a,b]$, which is $(a + b)/2$, we have that:

For each $n$, if $A_{n} = [\frac{a + b}{2} - \frac{1}{n}, \frac{a + b}{2} + \frac{1}{n}]$, then $\sup \limits_{x \in A_{n}} M_{x} \not < \infty$.

In particular, find $x_{n} \in A_{n}$ so that $M_{x_{n}} > n$.  Then by construction of $x_{n}$, we have $x_{n} \to (a+b)/2$, while $M_{x_{n}} \to \infty$.

Since $M_{x_{n}}$ is the *smallest* bound of $\{|f_{m}(x_{n})|\}_{m = 1}^{\infty}$, this implies that $\{ |f_{n}( \frac{a + b}{2})| \}_{n = 1}^{\infty}$ is unbounded, which contradicts that the sequence $f_{n}$ is pointwise bounded.

Comment: That doesn't work. If $$f_n{x} = \begin{cases}\quad n^2\cdot x &, \lvert x\rvert \leqslant \frac{1}{n} \\ n(2-n\lvert x\rvert) &, \frac{1}{n} < \lvert x\rvert \leqslant \frac{2}{n} \\ \qquad 0 &, \lvert x\rvert > \frac{2}{n},\end{cases}$$ then $\sup\limits_{x \in [-\varepsilon,\varepsilon]} M_x = +\infty$ for all $\varepsilon > 0$, but $f_n(0) = 0$ for all $n$.

Comment: There is another (less reliable) way to know that the solution is not likely correct.  The proof makes no use of the continuity of the functions.  If it were true then the statement could merely have been that each function $f_n$ is bounded on $[a,b]$.   While stronger statements *can* be true you should always be suspicious when your attempt at a proof neglects to use the assumptions.

Comment: @DanielFischer Good example.  I'm going to keep my answer up even though it's wrong in case anyone working on this problem might try a similar approach to proving before coming here.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer @user46944 :-)

Comment: Thanks as usual @danielfischer for your insightful comments :-).   I will keep trying this problem for a bit longer ...

Comment: Hi @DanielFischer, would a uniform continuity argument be a good approach?  Continuous functions over compact sets are automatically uniformly continuous.  (I should probably show this rather than just cite  it, too.)  From here, perhaps I can get a uniform bound on some subinterval in [a,b] ...

Comment: Hi @DanielFischer, for contradiction, assuming that we cannot achieve uniform boundedness on any subinterval, is this the same thing as saying that there is some point x in [a,b] such that $f_n(x)$ > M, for all M>0? (This seems to go against the assumption of pointwise boundedeness, though.)  I am giving a proof by contradiction another attempt but just want to make sure that I am starting out correctly...thanks,

Comment: @LebronJames A uniform bound is one number that bounds every function in the sequence.  So if you want to assume there is no uniform bound, it means you are assuming for every number, it can't be a bound for every function in the sequence. i.e., for every $M > 0$, we can find some point $f_{N}$ in the sequence so that for some $x$, $|f_{N}(x)| > M$.