# How to achieve uniform boundedness without functional analysis?

Tags: real-analysis

If $f_n(x)$ is cts on [a,b], and pointwise-bounded on this set, how could I show that there must exist a subinterval such that we achieve a uniform bound?  I've spent awhile on this problem but still have no real progress on it unfortunately.

I've read online a bit today and achieving uniform boundedness is apparently one of the big theorems in functional analysis.  But I am preparing for advanced calculus / non-measure theoretic analysis exams -- the above question is a former exam question.

Do you see a way to solve it without any version of Baire category theorem or functional analysis?

Contradiction seems to be the way to go - but I'm not sure whether to contradict the assumption of continuity, pointwise boundedness or perhaps both ...

Thanks,

Comment: Pointwise bounded in $n$ or in argument of $f$?

Comment: For every x, the set {f_n(x)} is bounded for n = 1,2,...thanks,@gudsonchou

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Baire theorem is the more natural way to your result, but perhaps what follows is an alternative:

Suppose that there do not exists such an interval. Put $u_0=a$, $v_0=b$. We can find a $x_0\in [a,b]$ and a $n_0$ such that $|f_{n_0}(x_0)|>1$. By continuity, we can find $u_1,v_1$, with $u_0<u_1<v_1<v_0$ and $\displaystyle v_1-u_1 \leq \frac{v_0-u_0}{2}$, such that $|f_{n_0}(x)|>1$ for all $x\in [u_1,v_1]$. Now we can find a $x_1\in [u_1,v_1]$ and a $n_1>n_0$ such that $|f_{n_1}(x_1)|>2$, and we can find $u_2,v_2$ such that $u_1<u_2<v_2<v_1$ and $\displaystyle v_2-u_2\leq  \frac{v_1-u_1}{2}$, etc. Hence by induction, we get a sequence of intervals $[u_k,v_k]$, with $u_k<u_{k+1}<v_{k+1}<v_k$ , $\displaystyle v_{k+1}-u_{k+1}\leq  \frac{v_k-u_k}{2}$, and $n_{k+1}>n_k$, with the property that $|f_{n_k}(x)|>k+1$ on $[u_k,v_k]$. Now $u_k$, $v_k$ converge to a same limite $x$, and we have $x\in [u_k,v_k]$ for all $k$, and hence $|f_{n_k}(x)|>k+1$ for all $k$, a contradiction.

Comment: Hi @kelenner how do you know that $|f_{n_0}(x_0)|>1$ ... and that $|f_{n_1}(x_1)|>2$, etc?  Thanks,

Comment: We have made the hypothesis that for any interval $[u,v]$, there does not exists a constant $M$ such that $|f_n(x)|\leq M$ for all $n$, and  $x\in [u,v]$. . So for $[u_1,v_1]$ and $M=2$, there must exist an $n_1$ and $x_1\in [u,v]$ such that $|f_{n_1}(x_1)|>2$.

Comment: To clarify a bit (unnecessarily). Let $A_1$  be the set of points $x$  where $|f_n(x)|\leq 1$ for all $n$. If $A_1$   contains no  interval, there must be a point $x_0\not\in A_1$.  Argue: (i)  since $A_1$ is closed (by continuity) there is an interval $[u_1,v_1]$ containing $x_0$ that doesn't meet $A_1$ or (ii)  since $x_0\not\in A_1$ there is an
integer $n_0$ so that $|f_{n_0}(x_0)|>1$ and then by continuity
there is  $[u_1,v_1]$ containing $x_0$ that doesn't meet $A_1$ because $|f_{n_0}(x )|>1$  there.
Repeat for $A_2$, etc.  Focus on the intervals, not the arithmetic used to produce them.

Comment: Tricky argument, but I think I got it, for the most part @Kelenner - thanks so much for your time and help.  For awhile, I could not understand why you had to even use the continuity assumption, but I think that allows you to then let k go to infinity to contradict the pointwise boundedness assumption at some (limit) point.  In fact, I think the continuity assumption *forces* k to go to infinity, which makes the proof work.  Am I correct @Kelenner?  Thanks,

Comment: The use of the  continuity assumption is in short the following: If you have given a continuous function $f$ on an interval $I$ and a constant $A$, and if for an $x_0\in I$, we have $|f(x_0)|>A$, then there exists $\alpha>0$ such that for $|x-x_0|<\alpha$, $x\in I$, we have $|f(x)|>A$. Then we can find $u,v$ with $u<v$ (and $[u,v]\subset (]x_0-\alpha,x_0+\alpha[)\cap I$), such that $|f(x)|>A$ on $[u,v]$

Comment: Hi @kelenner thanks for your comment and I'm sorry if this is annoying ... but I was wondering *why* the continuity assumption is needed?  (I understand how it is being used.). It appears that it's necessary because then it forces your quantifier, k, to go to infinity - hence we contradict pointwise boundedness with your upper bound at some point, x.  Is this the right motivation?  Thanks so much,

Comment: ...so that $n_k$ is forced to be greater than $n_{k-1}$ @kelenner.  what do you think?  thanks,

Comment: For the fact that we can find $n_k>n_{k-1}$, suppose not Then for $n\geq 1+n_{k-1}$ and $x\in I_k=[u_k,v_k]$, we have $|f_n(x)|\leq k+1$.Take $M\geq k+1$, and $M\geq {\rm Sup}_{x\in T_k}\{|f_n(x)|\}$ for $n=1,\cdots n_{k-1}$. Then we have $|f_n(x)|\leq M$ for all $n$ and $x\in I_k$, a contradiction as our assumption is that such an interval does not exists.

Answer (score 1):

*[We have continued from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1548186/how-can-pointwise-boundedness-on-an-interval-prove-uniform-boundedness-on-a-sub/1548263#1548263) where the same question was first raised by Lebron.]*

Mr Kelenner's proof uses only the basics of continuity and the nested interval argument.  So, on the face of it, it might seem that Mr Lebron James (who is currently taking a well-deserved respite from his basketball career) should be pleased that he has avoided a more sophisticated argument.

However ... the Baire category theorem on the real line is *not* deep, sophisticated, or difficult, and should by no means be avoided.  A short proof is available using only the same nested interval argument.  Do understand there is no functional analysis here and no measure theory.  Just basic real analysis ideas provable by nested interval arguments.

Indeed Mr  Kelenner's proof is just a category argument well-concealed.  The reason he was able to formulate the argument is that he already well knows the nature of the problem and can write it up in a way that contains anyway the essence of the Baire category proof.  So instead of appealing directly to the Baire theorem, he slips a proof into the solution without comment.

> Here is the essence:  Suppose that $E_1$, $E_2$, ... is a sequence of
>   closed sets covering $[a,b]$.  Then one of these sets contains an
>   interval $[c,d]$.  If not, then choose a nested sequence of intervals
>   $\{[a_n,b_n]\}$ with $[a_n,b_n]$ containing no point of $E_n$.   The
>   intervals shrink to a point $z$ that does not belong to any of the
>   sets $E_n$, which is a contradiction.

Now let me dissect the Kelenner  proof.  Define $A_m$ to 
be the collection of all points $x \in [a,b]$ such that
$|f_n(x)|\leq m$ for all $n$.  By continuity each $A_m$ is
closed and by the pointwise bounded assumption every point of $[a,b]$ is in one of the sets.

If there is no subinterval contained in any
one of the set $A_m$ then  choose a nested sequence of intervals $[a_m,b_m]$ with $[a_m,b_m]$
containing no point of $A_m$.

The intervals shrink to a point $z$ that does not belong to any of the sets $A_m$, which is a contradiction.

[The Kelenner  write  up just directly finds the intervals outside the $A_m$ without commenting that $A_m$ is closed and uses continuity there.]

One can see that the proof already contains anyway a proof of the Baire category theorem.

---

*Moral*:  You want to avoid learning the simple Baire category theorem but, in the end, your proof has to include exactly the same reasoning that you wished to avoid.  Things get easier when you learn a wee bit more, not harder.  You have to learn this trick anyway, why not give it a name and use it whenever you need it.

Here are some more problems that you can try for practice that will illustrate.  Try proving using only the nested interval argument and then try for a category argument.  They are from
[Elementary Real Analysis](http://www.classicalrealanalysis.info/documents/TBB-AllChapters-Landscape.pdf).

> **Problem** 6.9.3 Suppose that  $f_n:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ are continuous and $\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)=0$ for each $x$.  Show that,
>   for any $\epsilon>0$, there is an interval $[c,d]$ so that $|f_n(x)|<
>   \epsilon$ for all $x\in [c,d]$. (Show not necessarily the case that
>   this holds on $[a,b]$.)
>
> **Problem** 6.9.4 Suppose that  $f_n:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ are continuous and $\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)=\infty$ for each $x$.  Show
>   that, for any $M>0$, there is an interval $[c,d]$ so that $f_n(x)>M$ for
>   all $x\in [c,d]$. (Show not necessarily the case that this holds on
>   $[a,b]$.)

Comment: Hi Professor Thomson, thanks so much for your time - I understand the problem a lot better now than two nights ago, I think.  Thanks in particular for your candid suggestions.  My work was almost right, but I was stuck on the part of using the continuity assumption -- it didn't seem necessary to use, in order to contradict the pointwise-boundedness assumption.  But as I commented in Kelenner's solution, I think that the continuity forces k to go to infinity, which is exactly what we wanted.  Please feel free to comment further if you'd like.  Thanks again @B.S.Thomson,