# One generalization of Uniform Boundness Theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $X$ a Banach Space and $Y$ a Normed Space.

Consider the sequence $(f_n)_n^\infty$  in $C(X,Y) = \{f:X \to Y | f$ is continuos function $\}$ such that  $sup\|f_n(x)\| \leq \infty$ $\forall x \in X$

Prove that:

$ \forall A \neq \emptyset$ open set of X, Exist  $M \in \mathbb{R} $ and $O \subset A$ open set such that $sup\|f_n(x) \| \leq M $ $\forall x \in O$ and $\forall n\in N$

Some hints ?

Comment: Use Baire. See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1548186/how-can-pointwise-boundedness-on-an-interval-prove-uniform-boundedness-on-a-sub).

Comment: It seems like something is missing? I could be wrong, but if $X=Y=\mathbb{R}$, consider the sequence $f_n(x)=\frac{n}{1+x^2}$. The sequence satisfies $\|f_n\|_\infty<\infty$ for all $n$, but no such $M$ exists for any subinterval of $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @charlestoncrabb The supremum is taken over $n$, not $x$, in the hypothesis.

Comment: @DavidMitra Gotcha, so should it be a strict inequality in the second line?

Comment: @charlestoncrabb Oh, of course. I didn't notice that...